# data-ng-repeat: how to set different options according to the index

Tags: angularjs, list

Sorry if this look like a stupid question but I have just started using `angular.js` and certain things are not easy to catch.

I have a list of numbers which I am showing using this:

```html
<li data-ng-repeat="i in getNumber(list) track by $index" data-ng-click="myFunction($index)" data-ng-class="myClass">{{$index+1}}</li>
```

This is showing my list as 1 2 3 4 5 etc

I'd like to change this to show something different upon reaching a specific index, i.e.

`if index == 5` then show ABCD instead of `{{$index+1}}`

Is it something I can achieve with `ng-repeat` or do I need to use a different approach?

Thanks a lot for the input

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it inside the interpolation markup `{{`...`}}` only, as we can do all normal javascript operations inside it:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <li data-ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] track by $index">
      {{ $index === 5 ? 'ABCD' : $index+1 }}
    </li>
  </div>
</section>
```